# GOT: "twins to the first"

Tags: collocation

Yo, I got stucked in reading game of thrones song of ice and fire at prolog part on this sentence:

> They emerged silently from the shadows, **twins to the first.** Three
>   of them....four...five...

I don't get this collocation and preposition to the first - means like "firstly" so like firstly twins appeared ? this however i found quite weird - why he called them twins, are white walkers all indentical?bear with me, iam just trying to understand :-)

Answer (score 5):

CONTEXT IS EVERYTHING:

> The Other halted. Will saw its eyes; blue, deeper and bluer than any human eyes, a blue that burned like ice. They fixed on the longsword trembling on high, watched the moonlight running cold along the metal. For a heartbeat he dared to hope.
>      They emerged silently from the shadows, twins to the first.

These apparitions are "twins to" (exactly like) the first Other.